# Detect if coreutils is installed on mac

Tags: bash, macos, gnu-coreutils

Without using [brew](https://brew.sh), how can I detect if coreutils is installed on the mac where my bash script is running.

here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

check_bash_version () {
  echo "checking which bash version is installed...."
  sleep 3
  echo "Bash versioncheck completed"
  sleep 1
  if [[ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -lt 4 ]]; then
    echo "You need to be using Bash version =< 4. Please upgrade"
    exit 1
  fi
}

check_coreutils () {
  echo "checking if coreutils is installed...."
  sleep 3
  # what goes here
}

main() {
  # Main function.

  # check if MacOS
  if [[ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]]; then
    check_bash_version
    check_coreutils
  fi
}
```

Comment: 1. Pick a tool from coreutils. 2. Output `--version` of this tool. 3. Check if the output has the string GNU in it.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk. If you make your comment an answer, then I can accept

Comment: Unrelated. Your error message should be `You need to be using bash version >= 4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the existence of GNU tools is done by using the output of `--version` from the tool and checking if it has the string `GNU` in it.

Comment: This works only if you actually *replace* mac's old BSD version of coreutils with the GNU ones. If you install GNU coreutils via homebrew, they do not replace them but are installed on a side, in brew's folders and are called by the binary name prefixed with `g`, so e.g. `gcomm` instead just `comm`. So if e.g. `comm --version` does not return GNU string you should also check `gcomm --version`.

Comment: If you wish to automatically use the installed versions instead of the default ones you can execute the following:
`echo 'export PATH=\"/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:\$PATH\"' >> ~/.bash_profile`